# Port is open but service is stopped

Tags: services, mail, nmap, netstat

I have interesting statstistics on open ports on ubuntu.

I scan my server from outside with `nmap`

And I see that

```
110/tcp  open     pop3
```

And many other ports are also open

But on the server itself with `netstat -nap` I don't see these ports

And any possible email services are stopped

I don't know how to proceed my check and how to close all these ports.

Comment: Whats the output of `netstat -nap | grep ':110.*LISTEN'` ?

Comment: @heemayl, it's empty

Comment: @heemayl, but ssh  ip  -p 110
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Comment: Then check the `nmap` carefully..if any service is not listening on that port then `nmap` is mistaking..can you check the IP whether you are running for the right machine..

Comment: @heemayl, yes, ip is correct, something wrong with the server, instead of  responding as 'Connection refused' it responds 'Connection closed by remote host'

Comment: use `telnet ip 110`

Comment: @heemayl, telnet ip 110, Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: Are you scanning the outside of a gateway (NAT) device that does port forwarding from the Internet side? If so, and port forwarding is still enabled for those ports they may show as open. Scan the box from internal on its private IP and see if you get the same results.

Comment: `sudo netstat -nape --inet` will list actual open connections. Btw, `ssh` uses port 22 by default, not 110. `sudo lsof -i` is informative, too.

Comment: @ fog: Use [`nc`, a.k.a. netcat(1)](http://askubuntu.com/tags/netcat), to look at a TCP-based service. Or, from a Windows machine, PuTTY in the Raw mode. Definitely not ssh(1).